# Importing Facebook Posts to an iPhone App

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook, fbconnect

I'm new to Xcode and wondering if one can help me in how to import a facebook fan page posts to an iphone app? When importing the posts, the app's users should be able like/comment on any post.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, you should look at the Facebook's provided iOS SDK which works seamlessly.

[Facebook iOS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/ios/)

And you'll find what you want here through a graph api request.
[Facebook iOS SDK Request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/request/)

If you need it, I can provide you more guidance than that, but that shouldn't be necessary ;-)

Comment: I'll go through it and will it you if more assistance might be needed. Thanks Mathieu